# How to express structural equality between trees in Alloy?

Tags: tree, equality, alloy, structural-equality

I have defined the following Alloy model that
uses a single State object to point to the roots of two trees `State.a` and `State.b`.

```
sig N {
  children: set N
}

fact {
  let p = ~children |
    ~p.p in iden
    and no iden & ^p
}

one sig State {
  a: one N,
  b: one N
}

fun parent[n:N] : N {
  n.~children
}

fact {
  no State.a.parent
  no State.b.parent
  State.a != State.b
  State.a.^children != State.b.^children
}

pred show {}

run show for 4
```

Among the solutions I get:

```
                 +-----+
              +--+State|+-+
             a|  +-----+  |b
              |           |
              v           v
             +--+       +--+
             |N2|       |N3|
             ++-+       +-++
              |           |
             +v-+       +-v+
             |N0|       |N1|
             +--+       +--+
```

So I get two trees `N2 -> N0` and `N3 -> N1` that are
structurally equal.

How can I further constraint this model so that `State.a` and `State.b`
are not equal in this sense?

I am afraid that this can only be done with a recursive predicate and
recursion is only possible to a limit of depth 3 (I think).

Therefore, I would favour a non-recursive solution if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You said everything right about the recursion the recursion depth.  I just tried the following recursive predicate, which did work fine for small trees

```
pred noniso[n1, n2: N] {
  #n1.children != #n2.children or 
  some nn1: n1.children, nn2: n2.children | noniso[nn1, nn2]
}
```

Another way to achieve this, which doesn't require recursion, is to model the `noniso` relationship as an Alloy relation, and then assert for all nodes that this relation contains all non-isomorphic pairs.  You could do that like this

```
one sig G {
  noniso: N -> N
} {
  all n1, n2: N {
    (n1 -> n2 in noniso) iff 
      (#n1.children != #n2.children or 
       some nn1: n1.children, nn2: n2.children | nn1 -> nn2 in noniso)
  }
}
```

To put this to test, I created `show_noniso` and `show_iso` predicates that create trees with 4 levels of nesting.

```
// differ at level 4 only
pred show_noniso[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7: N] {
  children = n1 -> n2 + n2 -> n3 + n3 -> n4 + n5 -> n6 + n6 -> n7
  State.a = n1
  State.b = n5
}

pred show_iso[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8: N] {
  children = n1 -> n2 + n2 -> n3 + n3 -> n4 + n5 -> n6 + n6 -> n7 + n7 -> n8
  State.a = n1
  State.b = n5
}
```

and then ran various combinations

```
// USING RECURSION_DEPTH SET TO 2
run noniso_recursion_fails {
  some disj n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7: N | show_noniso[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7]
  noniso[State.a, State.b]
} for 8 expect 0

run noniso_relation_works {
  some disj n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7: N | show_noniso[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7]
  State.a -> State.b in G.noniso
} for 8 expect 1

run iso_relation_works {
  some disj n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8: N | show_iso[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8]
  State.a -> State.b in G.noniso
} for 8 expect 0
```

The results of these analyses were as expected

```
   #1: no instance found. noniso_recursion_fails may be inconsistent, as expected.
   #2: instance found. noniso_relation_works is consistent, as expected.
   #3: no instance found. iso_relation_works may be inconsistent, as expected.
```